# Update Multiple records in my firebase with angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

update all the records in my firebase. i'm trying to create a reset button for all the ratings in my app but my firebase doesn't get updated is there a way to update/set all records. i have no problem updating individual records but all data ...
e.g `

```
$scope.books.rating = 0
$scope.books.$save
```

like an equivalent to

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET new_column = new value
```

updating all rows in sql.

Answer (score 1):

I regularly wipe all data in my Firebases with a code snippet like:

```
new Firebase('https://my.firebaseio.com/path/to/root').remove();
```

Even when I have objects (from AngularFire's `$asObject`) or arrays (from AngularFire's `$asArray()`) bound to that Firebase, they will be updated correctly when I execute that snippet.

Keep in mind that AngularFire is just a wrapper around Firebase's regular JavaScript API, to make it interact more nicely with AngularJS. For operations that don't require three-way sync, you can (and probably should) still the regular JavaScript API.

Comment: .remove deletes from the database i'm tryin to update in this scenario. like set it back to zero

Comment: its not the same thing as path/to/root includes the firebase ids.and i'm trying to update multiple rows in firebase

Comment: Wow... that was not at all obvious from your original question. You can just loop over all children and set the value back to 0.